# Scala 2.12 and Travis.ci - how to exclude the combination with Java 6?

Tags: scala, travis-ci

Adding Scala 2.12 to `.travis.yml` produces a new problem for me, because now the builds will fail under Java 6:

```
language: scala

scala:
  - 2.12.0
  - 2.11.8
  - 2.10.6

jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
  - openjdk6
```

How can I fix this to exclude the combination (scala 2.12.0, jdk opendjk6)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple search rendered the answer you are looking for, i believe your travis.yml needs this configuration

```
matrix:   # scala 2.12 requires java 8   exclude:
    - scala: 2.12.0-M5
      env: JDK=oraclejdk7
    - scala: 2.12.0-M5
      env: JDK=openjdk7
    - scala: 2.12.0-RC1
      env: JDK=oraclejdk7
    - scala: 2.12.0-RC1
      env: JDK=openjdk7
    - scala: 2.12.0-RC2
      env: JDK=oraclejdk7
    - scala: 2.12.0-RC2
      env: JDK=openjdk7
    - scala: 2.12.0
      env: JDK=oraclejdk7
    - scala: 2.12.0
      env: JDK=openjdk7
```

https://github.com/typesafehub/scala-logging/blob/master/.travis.yml

Answer (score 6):

The answer of @DevZer0 is correct. I want to add that one has to change syntax as well. In order to make the matrix exclusion work, instead of

```
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
  - openjdk6
```

one now has to use

```
env:
  - JDK=oraclejdk8
  - JDK=openjdk6

before_script:
  - jdk_switcher use $JDK
```

My complete script:

```
language: scala

scala:
  - 2.12.0
  - 2.11.8
  - 2.10.6

env:
  - JDK=oraclejdk8
  - JDK=openjdk6

before_script:
  - jdk_switcher use $JDK

matrix:
  # scala 2.12 requires java 8
  exclude:
    - scala: 2.12.0
      env: JDK=openjdk6
```